# How can I write an array to a file with quotes around every value?

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm trying to write an array to a CSV file. In the past, I've just used:

```
my_array.to_csv
```

and quotes be damned. But I have to conform on this particular file I'm writing to the CSV "standard". That means that, where this:

```
 a,b,c,"d, with a comma",e
```

was satisfactory before, now I must output:

```
"a","b","d, with a comma","e"
```

There must be some easy way, but I can't find it.

I tried:

```
x.map{|v| '"' + v + '"'}.to_csv
```

but the file ended up with:

```
"""a""","""b""","""c"""
```

I've tried a bunch of variations on that. I ALWAYS end up with 3 quote characters.

The only thing that works is this:

```
fout.puts x.map{|v| "\"#{v}\"" }.to_csv.gsub('"""','"')
```

Which of course is hideous. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add an option:

`my_array.to_csv(force_quotes:true)`

You can check out more options [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#DEFAULT_OPTIONS)

Comment: Show a link to the option so the OP can read about other options.

Answer (score -1):

better way follow
assuming a is array initially

`a ="'" + a.join("','") + "'"`

Comment: This is not a better way. It's naively and blindly wrapping single quotes around columns and inserting commas, which will fail if a column contains commas or single quotes. Use the [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) class as it knows how to follow the spec.